# C++ and wxWidgets - Rasterisation - line width and filling

Tags: c++, graphics, drawing, rasterizing

Is there a modification of Bresenhman (or any) algorithm to draw line with defined line width? I can only use DrawPoint(x,y) function. And second question: how to implement filling a figure (for example i draw a triangle and how to make a fill). Please help :)

Comment: You can use DrawLine and a pen with a certain size to draw a line with any specified line width.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>All you need is inside [wxDC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html) class. A small tutorial is [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=405047&seqNum=3).</strike>

How to implement polygon filling: [The Polygon Primeval](http://downloads.gamedev.net/pdf/gpbb/gpbb38.pdf) by Michael Abrash.

How to draw a line with a width: Extrude the 2-point line to a 4-point box and use the above algorithm.

Comment: As I wrote I can only use DrawPoint function. Other functions (eg. DrawCircle etc.) I must implement myself